# Getting 404 while hitting my REST application developed using Spring Boot on standalone tomcat

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat, spring-boot

I am not able to hit my REST api developed using Spring Boot and Java 8 on a standalone tomcat. Getting 404 when I hit it through my browser. However, the same application when hit through embedded tomcat, works.

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.study.rest</groupId>
    <artifactId>hello-world-rest-demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>hello-world-rest-demo</name>
    <description>Hello World REST API - Spring Boot</description>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.3.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- 
        To make the application both executable with embedded tc and also deployable on standalone tc. 
        Make sure to change the artifact packaging type from jar to war (see up)
        -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <fork>true</fork>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

**META-INF/context.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context path="/hello-world-rest-demo"/>
```

**BasicRestApplication.java**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class BasicRestApplication extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(BasicRestApplication.class, args);
    }

    /*
    For starting the application in standalone TC
     */
    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
        return application.sources(BasicRestApplication.class);
    }

}
```

**HelloWorldController.java**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api")
public class HelloWorldController {

    //URI: http://localhost:8080/api/products
    @RequestMapping(value = "/hello", method = RequestMethod.GET)
    public ResponseEntity<String> get() {
        return new ResponseEntity<>("Hello World", HttpStatus.OK);
    }

}
```

**Command:**

```
mvn spring-boot:run
```

Runs the application and display "`Hello World`" when I hit `http://localhost:8080/api/hello` in the browser

```
mvn clean install -DskipTests
```

Manually deploy the war on local tomcat and start it.
`http://localhost:8080/api/hello` in the browser gives `404`

Comment: i think you are missing  app- context path & server.servlet.path configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`path="/hello-world-rest-demo"` in `META-INF/content.xml` might be getting ignored, try using the context path (specified in `server.xml`) in the URL or the name of the `war` file, something like:

```
http://localhost:8080/<appName>/api/hello
```

Comment: That worked :) How come it is working without the application context name in embedded tomcat ?

Comment: Embedded Tomcat uses ```server.context-path``` property

Comment: If you set ```server.context-path=/blah``` when using embedded Tomcat, previous URL should be reachable using ```http://localhost:8080/blah/api/hello```

Answer (score 0):

Remove the path property from context.xml, if not specific reason to maintain it. Rather remove the context.xml file altogether. Spring boot facilitates independence from any xml based configuration.
Refer [this](http://www.lebanesemushroom.in/2017/01/debugging-java-spring-restful-jpa-with.html) blog's **Config goes away** section. 
You should see your REST api accessible from both the browser & embedded.